# Send string from thread bluetooth service to textView in main activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to send value from string (distance to obstacle) to my TextView in main activity.
I tried to use Handler, but still not working (crash) or receive nothing.

A part code which receive data from HC-05 (screen where you see in debug value assignet to variable)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdaOC.jpg)

```
@Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            while(true){
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    final String comingMsg = new String(buffer,0,bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG,"InputStream: " + comingMsg);
                    /*mHandler2.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Message message = new Message();
                            message.obj = comingMsg;
                            mHandler2.sendMessage(message);
                        }
                    });*/
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e(TAG,"Write: Error reading input." + e.getMessage());
                    active=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here It's parts of code from MainActivity where I tried put something to get values from service.
[I add, that for this moment i want to see something values from bluetooth in textView. Later I want to create parse string and send custom text to custom TextView - example: FL: (Front Left)- to one textView, FR: (Front Right) - to second textView]

There is method implementThreads(), because I wanted to do 6 Threads to 6 TextView which every time is refreshing value from string in Services (there I tried get value from Bluetooth Service)

```
Log.d(TAG,"Check intent - result");
    if(getIntent().getIntExtra("result",0)==RESULT_OK){
        mDevice = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("bonded device");
        myBluetoothService = new MyBluetoothService(getApplicationContext());
        startConnection(mDevice,MY_UUID);
        Log.d(TAG,"Check is active service");
        checkIfActive();
    }

    Log.d(TAG,"Check intent - connect_to_paired");
    if(getIntent().getIntExtra("connect_to_paired",0)==RESULT_OK){
        mDevice = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("bonded_paired_device");
        myBluetoothService = new MyBluetoothService(getApplicationContext());
        startConnection(mDevice,MY_UUID);
        Log.d(TAG,"Check is active service");
        checkIfActive();
    }

}


@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    myBluetoothService = new MyBluetoothService(getApplicationContext());
}

public void checkIfActive(){
    Log.d(TAG,"CheckIfActive: Started");
    if(myBluetoothService.active){
        Log.d(TAG,"CheckIfActive: Running method implementThreads()");
        implementThreads();
    }
}

public void implementThreads(){
    Log.d(TAG,"ImplementThreads: Started");
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                sleep(100);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

public void startConnection(BluetoothDevice device,UUID uuid){
    Log.d(TAG,"StartConnection: Initializing connection");
    myBluetoothService.startClient(device,uuid);
}
```

Thanks all for help, because It's very important for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to interect with UI Thread for operations like updating textviews etc.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //YOUR CODE HERE
                        Message message = new Message();
                        message.obj = comingMsg;
                        mHandler2.sendMessage(message);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Ok I put it for Service and on MainActivity in implementThreads() I put this code:

https://pastebin.com/raw/ujg3yHH2

It's not crashing, but still nothing happen with my textView. What I do wrong. Maybe I don't understand something in Handler. All messages is stored in Looper.